# I try to make a definition to perform the polynomial regression and I get several errors

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I try to make a def to perform polynomial regression and I get this error "Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead" and implemented "x = np.array (x, y) x = x.reshape (-1, 1)" and so I get this error "invalid index to scalar variable."

Also use this "x_train = x.to_numpy (). Reshape (-1,1)" and I get the first error I mentioned. If anyone can help me, I appreciate it in advance.

```
def R_Polinomial1(x,y): 
  x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x,y, test_size=0.2, random_state=20)
  poly = PolynomialFeatures(degree=2)
  train_x_poly = poly.fit_transform(x_train)
  train_x_poly
  clf = LinearRegression()
  train_y = clf.fit(train_x_poly, y_train)
  plt.scatter(x, y,  color='blue')
  XX = np.arange(3.0, 40.0, 0.1)
  YY = clf.intercept_[0]+ clf.coef_[0][1]*XX+ clf.coef_[0][2]*XX*XX
  plt.plot(XX, YY, '-r')
  plt.title("Regresion Polinomial de PWV v/s Modulo de elasticiad")
  plt.xlabel('PWV [m/s]')
  plt.ylabel('ME [MPa]')
  plt.grid()
  plt.show()
```

PWV and ME are columns of an excel that I use to be able to do this polynomial regression

Comment: It looks like the problem more likely with your inputs than your code. I think you are passing in a scalar (i.e a single number) rather than an array. Do `print(type(x))` in the first line of your function to see the datatype of the input. The input should be a "list" or "array" type, not a float.

Comment: I tried to implement that code, but it didn't solve the problem, you don't know how you want me to implement it. At least I put it at the beginning of the program

Comment: No, my suggestion won't fix your code. I don't think the problem is with the code itself, but with the inputs. I suspect that your input is a single value not an array of values. If the function `train_test_split` is `sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split`, then it expects x and y to be arrays, not single values. The print command I suggested will tell you what your inputs are.